# Which graphical libraries are used by Node-red to draw drag & drop nodes and also their connections

Tags: node-red

Which graphical libraries are used by Node-red to draw drag & drop nodes and also their connections.

I need to design a similar UI and found node red the best of all. This is why I'm asking this question.

Thanks

Comment: Node Red is open source, why don't take a look?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the main library used by node-RED UI editor is d3.js and according to the post in Node-RED forum [(click here)](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/node-red/view.js%7Csort:date/node-red/zZqe19sJpLQ/iXs4diyfpygJ) jQuery. If you want to check in GitHUB then search for the file /editor/js/ui/view.js [(click here)](https://github.com/node-red/node-red/blob/cf32a33984452d616221d2e36454d01acd7399ca/editor/js/ui/view.js). You will need to master HTML, SVG and CSS (further to d3.js) to build a similar UI.